# Using Altair to highlight area in faceted charts (similar to axhspan or axvspan)

Tags: python, graph, altair

I'm trying to include a yellow band in a faced graph using Altair, like in the image below:

[image]

However, I can not find a way to include this yellow band (in the graph above I used Photoshop). This typical way of doing this would be using layers, but when I try to include layers I receive the error 'ValueError: Faceted charts cannot be layered'.

Is there any way to avoid this problem?

The code for the graph (without the band) is below:

```
import altair as alt
import numpy as np
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.cars()

#adapting data
brand = list()
for i in source['Name']: brand.append(i.split(' ')[0])
source['Brand'] = brand

weight = list(set(source['Weight_in_lbs']))
weightArray = np.array_split(weight, 2)
weightClassification = list()
for weight_in_lbs in source['Weight_in_lbs']:
    if weight_in_lbs in weightArray[0]: weightClassification.append('light')
    if weight_in_lbs in weightArray[1]: weightClassification.append('heavy')
source['weight_classification'] = weightClassification

# remove empty columns
source = source.dropna(subset=['Horsepower', 'Brand', 'Origin', 'weight_classification'])

# define colors and shapes for weight_classification
colors = {"light": "orange", "heavy": "steelblue"}
shapes = {"light": "circle", "heavy": "square"}

chart = alt.Chart(source).mark_point().encode(
    x=alt.X("Brand:N", title=None, axis=alt.Axis(labelAngle=-90)), 
    y=alt.Y("Horsepower:Q", axis=alt.Axis(title='Horsepower', titleFontSize=17)), 
    color=alt.Color("weight_classification:N", scale=alt.Scale(domain=list(colors.keys()), range=list(colors.values()))),
    shape=alt.Shape("weight_classification:N", scale=alt.Scale(domain=list(shapes.keys()), range=list(shapes.values()))),
    tooltip=['Name', 'Origin', 'Horsepower', 'Miles_per_Gallon'],
    facet=alt.Facet('Origin:N', title=None, header=alt.Header(labelFontSize=13), type = "ordinal")
).configure_view(
    strokeOpacity=0
).resolve_scale(
    x='independent'
).properties(
    width=alt.Step(25),
    height=350
).configure_facet(
    spacing=20
).configure_axis(
    labelFontSize=17,
    labelLimit=500,
    labelAngle=-90
).configure_legend(labelLimit= 0, labelFontSize=13, titleFontSize = 15).interactive()


chart.save('AltairCar.html')
```

EDIT:

When I try to layer first and then facet, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67318821/bar-chart-in-altair-valueerror-faceted-charts-cannot-be-layered?rq=1), I have the error "**Facet charts require data to be specified at the top level**". The code that return this error is below:

```
import altair as alt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.cars()

#adapting data
brand = list()
for i in source['Name']: brand.append(i.split(' ')[0])
source['Brand'] = brand

weight = list(set(source['Weight_in_lbs']))
weightArray = np.array_split(weight, 2)
weightClassification = list()
for weight_in_lbs in source['Weight_in_lbs']:
    if weight_in_lbs in weightArray[0]: weightClassification.append('light')
    if weight_in_lbs in weightArray[1]: weightClassification.append('heavy')
source['weight_classification'] = weightClassification

# remove empty columns
source = source.dropna(subset=['Horsepower', 'Brand', 'Origin', 'weight_classification'])

# define colors and shapes for weight_classification
colors = {"light": "orange", "heavy": "steelblue"}
shapes = {"light": "circle", "heavy": "square"}

# define main chart
chart = alt.Chart(source).mark_point().encode(
    x=alt.X("Brand:N", title=None, axis=alt.Axis(labelAngle=-90), scale=alt.Scale(padding=1)), 
    y=alt.Y("Horsepower:Q", axis=alt.Axis(title='Horsepower', titleFontSize=17)), 
    color=alt.Color("weight_classification:N", scale=alt.Scale(domain=list(colors.keys()), range=list(colors.values()))),
    shape=alt.Shape("weight_classification:N", scale=alt.Scale(domain=list(shapes.keys()), range=list(shapes.values()))),
    tooltip=['Name', 'Origin', 'Horsepower', 'Miles_per_Gallon'],
).resolve_scale(
    x='independent'
).properties(
    width=alt.Step(25),
    height=350
).interactive()

# define yellow band
yellow_band = alt.Chart({'values': [{'y1': 100, 'y2': 140}]}).mark_rule(
    color='yellow',
    opacity=0.3,
    strokeWidth=3 # Define a espessura da linha
).encode(
    y=alt.Y('y1:Q', axis=alt.Axis(title='Horsepower', titleFontSize=17)),
    y2='y2:Q',
    x=alt.X('Brand:N')
)

# combine the two charts
final_chart = (chart + yellow_band).facet('Origin:N')

chart.save('AltairCar.html')
```

Comment: See if this answers your question, otherwise comment and I can reopen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67318821/bar-chart-in-altair-valueerror-faceted-charts-cannot-be-layered?rq=1

Comment: Sorry, but when I follow the example I receive the error "Facet charts require data to be specified at the top level". I edited my question to include the code returning this error.

Comment: I added a reply below and edited the title of your question

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the same data in all charts used in a facet (or specify the data in the facet itself). Here is an example of how you could set it up (not sure if it is possible to add "interactive" here, doesn't seem to work):

```py
# define main chart
chart = alt.Chart(source).mark_point().encode(
    x=alt.X("Brand:N", title=None, axis=alt.Axis(labelAngle=-90), scale=alt.Scale(padding=1)), 
    y=alt.Y("Horsepower:Q", axis=alt.Axis(title='Horsepower', titleFontSize=17)), 
    color=alt.Color("weight_classification:N", scale=alt.Scale(domain=list(colors.keys()), range=list(colors.values()))),
    shape=alt.Shape("weight_classification:N", scale=alt.Scale(domain=list(shapes.keys()), range=list(shapes.values()))),
    tooltip=['Name', 'Origin', 'Horsepower', 'Miles_per_Gallon'],
)

# define yellow band
yellow_band = alt.Chart(source).mark_rule(
    color='yellow',
    opacity=0.3,
    strokeWidth=3 # Define a espessura da linha
).encode(
    y=alt.datum(100),
    y2=alt.datum(140),
    x=alt.X('Brand:N')
)

# combine the two charts
alt.layer(
    chart,
    yellow_band
).properties(
    width=alt.Step(25),
    height=350
).facet(
    'Origin:N'
).resolve_scale(
    x='independent'
)
```

[image]

I am not sure how you can make that yellow area span all the categorical x-axis. Maybe create a simpler example without the facetting using mark rect and ask a new question?

Comment: Thank you very much! The whole reason why I want to use Altair and not Seaborn (I can create this figure with Seaborn) is because of the interactive function. I guess I will simply create multiple plots, and display them side by side in my HTML file (somehow faking a faceted plot). Thank you again.

Comment: @Rodrigo Yeah, it is annoying that it doesn't work there, not sure why. I reported it as a bug here https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/2924.